# unpivot grouped columns in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have some grouped field result and want to UNPIVOT the result into rows in mongodb 4.0. Please help. The following is the query :

```
    db.runCommand(
     {
    aggregate : 'testing',
    pipeline : [
       { "$group" : { "_id" :  null  , "currentDay" :
    { "$sum" : "$currentDay"/*Calculated Field */} ,
    "currentWeek" : { "$sum" : "$currentWeek"/*Calculated Field */} ,
    "prevWeek" : { "$sum" : "$prevWeek"/*Calculated Field */} ,
    "currentMonth" : { "$sum" : "$currentMonth"/*Calculated Field */} ,
    "currentYear" : { "$sum" : "$currentYear"/*Calculated Field */} ,
    "previousYear" : { "$sum" : "$prevYear"/*Calculated Field */}}}
   ]
   ,cursor : {batchSize : 10}
    }
 )


    Required Output : 
    [{
      d : 'Current Day',
      d1: 100 /*currentDay value */
      },
      {
      d : 'Current week',
      d1: 1000 /*currentWeek value */
      }         ,
     ----------------
        ]
```

Regards

Kris

Answer (score 0):

Appended to previous query I achieved the same by https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/

```
        {
     $project: {
        item: 1,
        dimensions: { $objectToArray: {'current Day':"$currentDay"
            ,'current Year' : '$currentYear','prev Year' : '$prevYear','current Month':'$currentMonth' }
     }
  }},
{$unwind : '$dimensions'} ,
  {$project : {d:'$dimensions.k',d1:'$dimensions.v',_id:0}}
```

Regards

Kris